# Best way to Step down 6V DC or 9V DC for 3.3V DC operation

Tags: buck, low-power, battery-operated

[image]

I am basing on TIs [TPS62745DSSR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62745.pdf?ts=1606733472644&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.de%252Furl%253Fsa%253Dt%2526rct%253Dj%2526q%253D%2526esrc%253Ds%2526source%253Dweb%2526cd%253D%2526ved%253D2ahUKEwiTrKjIjKrtAhVL3qQKHbgXAAIQFjAAegQIBBAC%2526url%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftps62745%2526usg%253DAOvVaw2JSAUYuLQvo5ljIqbzmV9G).

I have the circuit above and I want to use two CR2032 coin cell batteries to power VCC_IN. I have made this circuit based on info collected from the internet. My load is maximum 300mA.

I unsure on:

1. What does the MOSFET ([CJ2301](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/1085987/JCET/CJ2301S/1)) do in this case? Does it just smooth out the input voltage? Why would this be needed when I am using batteries anyway?
2. In every other buck "step-down" design I have seen a diode. Why would I not need one in this case?  Should I add one?
3. I am leaning towards making the C3 4.7uF capacitor a tantalum instead of ceramic. Does this make sense in this setup?

Comment: The best way? There simply is no way you can power a 1 watt load from two CR2032 batteries.

Comment: Taking a look at a datasheet for a typical 2032 (https://www.murata.com/en-us/products/productdata/8802803744798/CR2032X-DATASHEET.pdf) the recommended continuous discharge rate is 1mA.  The maximum discharge rate is 30mA to keep voltage above 2V on a half charge, for a maximum of 3 seconds.  With a converter operating at 100% efficiency, you will need 17 batteries in series just to get your current down to this level.  Maybe a LiPO pack?

Comment: Unless you're a student trying to *learn* something, the _"**best** way to step down 6V DC or 9V DC for 3.3V DC operation"_ is using a ready-made module. Search the habitual sellers for _"3.3v step-down"_ , and you will not need to deal with TPS62745DSSR and MOSFETs. But, anyway, 2032 batteries will *never* achieve the 300 mA required by your load.

Comment: Wow thank you justme, vir and mguima for your kind sharing of knowledge.  So maybe I need to look at my load again. The absolute peak will be 250mA. The load will be an atmega 328p and rfm95 Lora module. This project seems to have used it successfully but I don’t want to just copy without understanding - https://www.crowdsupply.com/easysensors/easyswitchbox.

Comment: Also another way to go with the power supply would be increasing the number of cells and using alkaline instead of lithium- https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/6/671.html. My use case is 20 short bursts of on/off status per day and I want to aim for 1 year plus in operating life.

Comment: The crowdsupply project isn't delivering yet, so it may not work.  In any case, they aren't just dropping the voltage.  They are drawing a low current from the coin cells, and storing it in a large capacitor at the lower voltage.  That way, they can draw a short burst of high current from the capacitor every now and again.  If you can do that, then it should be possible to get what you need from the coin cells.

Comment: What is the standby current? How long does the 250mA burst last? You will need a capacitor across the CR2032 cells. This capacitor will discharge according to dv/dt=i/C. So this may work if the capacitor is large enough to ensure voltage does not drop below spec during a burst, but you need to calculate the length of the burst and how much charge it will draw out of the cap to choose a large enough cap.

Comment: Looking at the typical application in the datasheet, your whole signal routing seems a bit strange. I suspect the MOSFET is there as an attempt to protect against reverse polarity, maybe? It has nothing to do with the regulator itself. And there's no obvious need for a tantalum cap, any ceramic with >10V rating will do just fine.

Comment: Your estimation of RFM95 power consumption seems rather high.  Transmit power is configurable, so you don't necessarily have to support the maximum capability, either.  Going in the other direction, at the more redundant spreading factors a packet may be very long in electronic terms - more than a second and and a half in Europe, shorter in some other places with regulatory limits.  So you may need a fairly large capacitor.  Overall running LoRa nodes on coin cells is uncommon, and usually only attempted in unique cases.  The engineering vs marketing of the linked project is questionable.

Answer (score 1):

1. The FET is for reverse polarity protection. This could be an issue because CR2032 cells can easily be installed backwards in some holders.
2. TPS62745 doesn't need an external flyback diode because it has an internal FET to perform this job. The technique is commonly called 'synchronous rectification', because the FET operates like a diode which is switched on and off in synchronism with the PWM. The FET also has a 'body' diode across it which does the job during switching before the FET turns on.
3. Possibly, depending on size of a Tantalum vs a ceramic capacitor with the required capacitance *at the working voltage*. Small high value ceramics often have reduced capacitance at higher voltage. however ceramic capacitors usually have lower ESR which reduces ripple. If you need much higher capacitance a combination of types might be best.